# Better way to do this rails / SQL query?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails SQL Query where I want tasks of a priority 2 AND has a substring of a larger string, ALL tasks with priority 1, and ALL tasks with priority 3

what would be a better  / more efficient way of doing the below query?

```
Task.where('large_string LIKE ?', '%' + substring + '%').or(Task.where(priority: 3)).or(Task.where(priority: 1)).all
```

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: `Task.where(Task.arel_table[:priority].eq(2).and(Task.arel_table[:large_string].matches("%#{substring}%")).or(Task.arel_table[:priority].in([1,3])))` should do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
Task
  .where(priority: 2)
  .where('large_string LIKE ?', "%#{sanitize_sql_like(substring)}%")
  .or(Task.where(priority: [1, 3]))
  .all
```

See [`sanitize_sql_like`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_like) and [`where` with subset conditions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#subset-conditions).

Comment: You missed the priority = 2 requirement (not shown in the code but stated in the question).